# Change shape of Button while mantaining its material design ripple effect

Tags: android, shapes, android-selector

I want to create Button with custom shape , which would react on press like in theme ***"Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"***.

However bacause of I have to customize its shape (rounded corners I have to override its `android:background` - this is so far the only way I know (no... no I will not use dirty hacks with *FrameLayout*). 
Currently it can be done **only** by providing our custom `<shape>` in xml file as background drawable.

The most promising code, which enable *selectableItemBackground* - so imporant for me, is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/button_shape_radius"
                android:topRightRadius="@dimen/button_shape_radius"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:drawable="?attr/selectableItemBackground">
        <shape>
            <solid/>
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/button_shape_radius"
                android:topRightRadius="@dimen/button_shape_radius"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Unfortunatelly I cannot shape second item with `<item android:drawable="?attr/selectableItemBackground">` therefore in the end pressed item's shape is rectangle.
[image]

I would appreaciate if someone will give me soulution for this problem. 
I use API_MIN = 16, so cannot use ripple effect.  I also dont want to use FrameLayout or tther external Library that forces me to wrapp Button with something.

Answer (score 1):

To have a ripple below 21 you can use this library  [Ripple Effect](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect) you use your shape without the ripple tag and surround the view with `RippleView` for more details you can check the `Usage` section

21+ you can try this i didn't test it but it should work, put this in the folder drawable-v21

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight">
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
        <corners android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/button_shape_radius"
            android:topRightRadius="@dimen/button_shape_radius"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:drawable="?attr/selectableItemBackground">
    <shape>
        <solid/>
        <corners android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/button_shape_radius"
            android:topRightRadius="@dimen/button_shape_radius"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</ripple>
```

**UPDATE**

I changed the source code of Ripple Effect to a button

You can get the code [here](https://github.com/tiagooliveira95/RippleButton/blob/master/RippleButton.java)

**USAGE**

Just like any ordinary button
 **XML**

```
<path.to.the.RippleButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_rounded_top_blue"
    android:id="@+id/mybutton"/>
```

**Java**

```
RippleButton button = (RippleButton) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this, "You did it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

If you need other view you just need to make some tweaks to the source code it's easy (in my opinion)

Comment: The library works, however it isn't the best soultion 4me, because I have to use every time wrapper outside my view, while I want to declarate **one** Button style in purpose of code reuse

Comment: yhe you are right, i was trying to do the same exact thing yesterday, i have 4 views on my app that fill the screen and i have to wrap every one with `Rippleview`, i tested  on a couple of devices and i got no performance issues, but my layout is simple

Comment: I didnt approved your answer because I hope that someone came up with something better

Comment: no need to worry about that :) but now im a bit curious to know if theres a better way if i find something i let you know

Comment: I did it :) is not that hard we just need to change a few lines, look at my edit you no longer need to wrap your button with the `RippleView` just need to change your botton to a `RippleButton`

Comment: Great work. I don't want to be inpolite, but I will still wait unless noone else answer